# Does anyone know how to get rid of the automatic HDR on Blender 2.8

Tags: glass, hdri

Hey so I'm new to Blender 2.8 and am creating an eye ball.
I just got finished with the outer eye and created a glass BSDF material for it to give it that shiny/glossy eyeball look. The only problem is that instead of the outer eye being transparent so that the inner eye is visible, the glass shader is reflecting, like a mirror, the HDR that automatically comes with Blender 2.8.
Does anyone know how to get rid of this HDR?

[image: 8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the hdri by using the rendered viewport mode or switching it with a different hdri in the user preferences.

In order to make glass transparent and refractive in eevee you have to enable screen space reflection and check the refraction option.

[image]

Then you have to go to the material settings and enable SSR there as well. I found that the alpha hashed blendmode works best.

[image]

Comment: How would one make the glass transparent and refractive in cycles?